# C# encrypt string variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to encrypt a text and save the encrypted text to a string
variable and a text file.

But the amazing thing is that the encrypted text in string doesn't look
the same as the encrypted text in a text file .

E.g string  =  bpAz1pcidPuCXbpO+5RYvQ==

```
textfile  = n3Ö—"tû‚]ºNû”X½
```

I would really like my string variable to have same data as my
textfile.txt . My intension is to encrypt the string variable not the textfile. 
So how do i encrypt my string variable to look the same way as my textfile data?

Here is my code below :

```
     byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my name is calito");

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        csEncrypt.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

        //copying encrypted text to string
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);

        //copying incrypted text to text file
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"G:\New Text Document.txt", memoryStream.GetBuffer());
```

Answer (score 4):

> But the amazing thing is that the encrypted text in string doesn't
>   look the same as the encrypted text in a text file .

That's because you are not writing the encrypted string to the file which is a Base64 representation of the actual buffer but you are writing the buffer itself. So if you wanted to write this Base64 string to the file you could use the [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) method:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"G:\New Text Document.txt", cipherText);
```

Comment: And _if_ you want the bytes in a memorystream, use .ToArray() instead. GetBuffer() may return a larger number of bytes than .Length indicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the textfile are the actual bytes. What you've got in the string is the base64 encoded variant of the same bytes.

Comment: Okay thanks. So is it possible to write buffer/actual bytes to my string variable? The reason why i want it this way is because i like the way buffer data is represented - that is it's not readable.

Comment: Oh i did get a solution. The following code  answers my question. 

memoryStream.Position = 0;
var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
cipherText = sr.ReadToEnd();        

Thank you for your efforts guys.